# How to work on Force.com projects in teams from the perspective of source control?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, eclipse

We are just starting force.com development after years of .NET.  Our organization is setup with TFS and it works pretty well.

I am a bit confused as to how to make TFS work with Force.com.  I've tried installing the TFS plugin into Eclipse but it proved to be a massive pain point. TFS keeps the files read-only and that interferes with `Refresh from Server` feature.  Secondly to edit a file, you have to first check it out in a separate window, then go and open it from the Package Explorer.  Anyway, not the most optimal way to work.

Another concern is change tracking.  In the .NET world, when I am fixing a bug, I just tell Visual Studio that it's in fact what I am doing...so when I check stuff in, it marks all my changes as part of the checkin to fix that bug.  That is incredibly helpful.  Not sure how to do that in Force.com

Finally, how does one do change tracking?  I'd like to see a history of who changed what on file X.  I didn't see a way to do it - at least not in force.com.

So my questions...

1. Is there an *effective* way to integrate TFS with Force.com?
2. Is there a way to associate a certain amount of changes with fixing a bug - either with force.com or TFS?
3. Anyway to do change tracking?  E.g. who changed what when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use SVN instead of TFS, but it's a similar principle. Here's some things that might help (or not).

1. Unless you're married to TFS, try using SVN. You can set it up in an afternoon and see if it works/could work/might work. Not all tools are created equal, and this might simply be one of those cases. Microsoft software isn't known to play well with non-Microsoft projects. Then again, maybe it's the version of Eclipse, or the plugin, etc. Try working with various combinations. I could only offer help with SVN, and I do hope someone posts a more formal TFS-based answer. You might also look at a GIT repository; GIT is just as good as SVN at what it does (or so I've heard).
2. Speaking again of SVN, you can select a number of files and run a 'Commit' that includes a comment. Each commit is bundled into a revision, which includes the revision ID (a number), a timestamp, who committed it, what files were committed, and the versions of those files. Any decent SVN application (including the plugin for Eclipse) lets you compare revisions on a per-file basis so you can see exactly what changed and who committed those changes. Discipline is key here. Each commit should fix exactly one item (we're guilty of breaking this rule, and it has cost us time finding what broke).
3. Not in salesforce.com. It only gives you a Last Modified Date and Last Modified By. No mention of "what" changed. This is the point of using SVN/TFS/GIT/etc. While I wish that there were ways of storing this all in the system, salesforce.com is fairly stingy with its storage space (we get 3MB for our entire app's code, 5000 classes, etc). I thought of writing a mini-IDE that was cloud-based for the platform that did something like this, but it would still take discipline. Hopefully salesforce.com will implement something like this in the future. For now, use a versioning control system to track those changes, and make people use it.